# Switch to new process' window when calling subprocess.Popen(...) in python+tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When I call `subprocess.Popen("python ./open_dialog.py")` in one python file (let's call it main.py) and open_dialog.py contains the following code:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
import shutil

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("jpg files","*.jpg")])
print file_path
```

I want the front/visible/selected window to be that of the new file dialog, but file dialog opens in the background unselected and I have to `Alt-tab` to get to it. Are there any flags that I can use for `subprocess.Popen()` or `os.system()` so that the newly created window is the window in front?

Comment: `os.system()` and `subprocess` don't care about windowing.  You need to somehow get "open_dialog.py" to force its window to be selected.  If you don't get an answer here, you need to look into the Tkiner documenation for that.

Comment: call `root.focus_set()`